# Use Swift's Encodable to encode optional properties as null without custom encoding

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding, codable

I want to encode an optional field with Swift's `JSONEncoder`using a `struct` that conforms to the `Encodable` protocol.

The default setting is that `JSONEncoder` uses the `encodeIfPresent` method, which means that values that are `nil` are excluded from the Json.

How can I override this for a single property without writing my custom `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` function, in which I have to implement the encoding for all properties (like [this article](http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/) suggests under "Custom Encoding" )?

Example:

```
struct MyStruct: Encodable {
    let id: Int
    let date: Date?
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(id: 10, date: nil)
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(myStruct)
print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!) // {"id":10}
```

Comment: Related question but using custom encoding logic instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266862/encode-nil-value-as-null-with-jsonencoder/47268112

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A `JSON` entry in the hash such as `"date": null;`? What difference do you intend to convey by making the `null` explicit? If you plan to consume the result using Swift you will have a really hard time to tell the difference in the first place. Your link seems to be the only notable reference to `encodeIfPresent`, but the case seems to be sufficiently rare to merit the implementation of `encode(to encoder: Encoder)`.

Comment: My API resets values by setting `null` explicitly on them. And from my experience, is not a rare case...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without implementing your own `encode`. (The pieces of JSONEncoder you'd need to override are `fileprivate`.) If it is non-trivial to implement, I would recommend SwiftGen to write it for you; this should be straightforward to build in SwiftGen. As a rule, it is not possible to get semi-custom Encodables. There are a small number of very specific configuration points, but beyond that, it's currently default or custom. I expect this to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a property wrapper for this.

### @CodableExplicitNull

```
import Foundation

@propertyWrapper
public struct CodableExplicitNull<Wrapped> {
    public var wrappedValue: Wrapped?
    
    public init(wrappedValue: Wrapped?) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}

extension CodableExplicitNull: Encodable where Wrapped: Encodable {
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch wrappedValue {
        case .some(let value): try container.encode(value)
        case .none: try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}

extension CodableExplicitNull: Decodable where Wrapped: Decodable {
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            wrappedValue = try container.decode(Wrapped.self)
        }
    }
}

extension CodableExplicitNull: Equatable where Wrapped: Equatable { }

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    
    public func decode<Wrapped>(_ type: CodableExplicitNull<Wrapped>.Type,
                                forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> CodableExplicitNull<Wrapped> where Wrapped: Decodable {
        return try decodeIfPresent(CodableExplicitNull<Wrapped>.self, forKey: key) ?? CodableExplicitNull<Wrapped>(wrappedValue: nil)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
struct Test: Codable {
    @CodableExplicitNull var name: String? = nil
}

let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(Test())
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")

let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: data)
print(obj)
```

Gives

```
{"name":null}
Test(name: nil)
```

Comment: Best solution so far. Can you explain why we need the extension on `KeyedDecodingContainer` ?

Comment: @heyfrank, the `KeyedDecodingContainer` stuff allows for compatibility with regular `Optional` properties coded as usual, i.e. omitted entirely. Simply speaking it allows for implicit nulls too when decoding.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Foundation

enum EncodableOptional<Wrapped>: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
    init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        self = .none
    }
}

extension EncodableOptional: Encodable where Wrapped: Encodable {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .none:
            try container.encodeNil()
        case .some(let wrapped):
            try wrapped.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }
}

extension EncodableOptional{

    var value: Optional<Wrapped> {

        get {
            switch self {
            case .none:
                return .none
            case .some(let v):
                return .some(v)
            }
        }

        set {
            switch newValue {
            case .none:
                self = .none
            case .some(let v):
                self = .some(v)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct User: Encodable {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var age: Int?
    var gender: EncodableOptional<String>
}

func main() {
    var user = User(name: "William", surname: "Lowson", age: 36, gender: nil)
    user.gender.value = "male"
    user.gender.value = nil
    print(user.gender.value ?? "")
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try! jsonEncoder.encode(user)
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)

    let dict: [String: Any?] = [
        "gender": nil
    ]
    let d = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    let j = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: d, options: [])
    print(j)
}

main()
```

This will give you output after executing main:

```
{
    age = 36;
    gender = "<null>";
    name = William;
    surname = Lowson;
}
{
    gender = "<null>";
}
```

So, you can see that we encoded gender as it'll be null in dictionary. The only limitation you'll get is that you'll have to access optional value via `value` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to encode single values.

```
struct CustomBody: Codable {
    let method: String
    let params: [Param]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case method = "method"
        case params = "params"
    }
}

enum Param: Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)
    case stringArray([String])
    case valueNil
    case unsignedInteger(UInt)
    case optionalString(String?)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode([String].self) {
              self = .stringArray(x)
              return
          }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(UInt.self) {
            self = .unsignedInteger(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Param.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Param"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .bool(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .stringArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .valueNil:
            try container.encodeNil()
        case .unsignedInteger(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .optionalString(let x):
            x?.isEmpty == true ? try container.encodeNil() : try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage is like this

```
RequestBody.CustomBody(method: "WSDocMgmt.getDocumentsInContentCategoryBySearchSource", 
                       params: [.string(legacyToken), .string(shelfId), .bool(true), .valueNil, .stringArray(queryFrom(filters: filters ?? [])), .optionalString(sortMethodParameters()), .bool(sortMethodAscending()), .unsignedInteger(segment ?? 0), .unsignedInteger(segmentSize ?? 0), .string("NO_PATRON_STATUS")])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you try to decode this `JSON` your trusty `JSONDecoder` will create exactly the same object as exemplified in this Playground:

```
import Cocoa

struct MyStruct: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let date: Date?
}

let jsonDataWithNull = """
    {
        "id": 8,
        "date":null
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

let jsonDataWithoutDate = """
    {
        "id": 8
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let withNull = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonDataWithNull)
    print(withNull)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

do {
    let withoutDate = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonDataWithoutDate)
    print(withoutDate)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print

```
MyStruct(id: 8, date: nil)
MyStruct(id: 8, date: nil)
```

so from a "standard" Swift point of view your distinction makes very little sense. You can of course determine it, but the path is thorny and leads through the purgatory of `JSONSerialization` or `[String:Any]` decoding and a lot more ugly optionals. Of course if you are serving another language with your interface that might make sense, but still I consider it a rather rare case which easily merits the implementation of `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` which is not hard at all, just a little tedious to clarify your slightly non-standard behaviour.

This looks like a fair compromise to me.