# Codable to Dictionary with nil value keys

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, codable

To convert Codable to Dictionary I have created this extension.

```
extension Encodable {
  func asDictionary() throws -> [String: Any] {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
      throw NSError()
    }
    return dictionary
  }
}
```

But I have special requirement like below.

```
struct Foo: Codable {
  let a: Foo1?
  let b: Foo2?
}
struct Foo1: Codable{
let x:String
}

struct Foo2: Codable{
let y:String
}

let foo: Foo = Foo(a:Foo1(x:"hello"),b: nil)
let dict = foo.asDictionary
```

**Actual Output :** {a:{x:hello}}

**Excepted Output :** {a:{x:hello,y:nil}}

How we can do this getting key with nil values?

Comment: if you make it to Any it does not work. Because Any does not conform to Codable.

Comment: `"{"a":{"x":"hello"},"b":null}"` Did you mean a json string?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47268112/2303865

Comment: Verified that this can be solved using the above linked case