# Alamofire swift how to keep JSON keys in POST request even if value is null / nil

Tags: json, swift, null, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 5.6.2 with the following JSON encoder:

```
let encoder = JSONParameterEncoder.json()
encoder.encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.standard)
encoder.encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
```

And then using it in a POST request like this:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        .authorization(bearerToken: token),
        .accept("application/json"),
        .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"),
        .acceptEncoding("utf-8")
    ]
            
    AF.request(path, method: .post, parameters: data, encoder: encoder, headers: headers).validate().responseDecodable(of: R.self, decoder: decoder) { response in
        switch response.result {
            ...
        }
```

The `data` parameter is an object like the following:

```
struct SampleRequest: Codable {
    var param1: Bool
    var param2: Float?
}
```

And the problem is, if `param2` is nil, the key won't be added to the request body. This is a problem for me since the endpoint I'm targeting uses the same request flow for different update tasks, and it needs to know if a particular key is nil in order to set it as null in the backend, or it's not present and hence it shouldn't do anything with it.

I can't find any options on the `JSONParameterEncoder.json()` encoder I'm using in order to keep the keys when the value is nil. How could this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not Alamofire, it's `Foundation.JSONEncoder` & `Encodable` behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266862/encode-nil-value-as-null-with-jsonencoder

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out, I already implemented something like it's suggested on that issue and it worked. Feel free to move the comment to a "proper" (with all due respect) answer and I'll accept it, thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode nil value as null with JSONEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266862/encode-nil-value-as-null-with-jsonencoder)